# Select final state of a row with versioning

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, conditional-aggregation

I have a table like this

```
ID  Value1  Value2  value3  Versioning
1   sport   tennis    2         1
1   NULL    NULL      4         2
1   NULL    football NULL       3
1   game    NULL     NULL       4
```

This is actually a Custom replicated table from one database to another. The logic is the following:
The first row you replicate (versioning=1) comes with all its fields . Then every time you have any update on the original table only the changed values are replicated and not the whole table. So after 4 versionings we end up like above. What i need to do is to create a query that can read this table and return only one row that is actually the last state. 
Using our example table my desired outcome will be

```
ID Value1 Value2      Value3
1   game   football     4
```

Explaining the outcome for Value1 int the 1st  version i have 'sport' in the 2nd and 3rd we dont have any change and in 4th version it was updated to 'game' . Respectively for the other values we have tennis -> No change -> football -> No change and for value 3  we have 2 -> 4-> No change -> No change with each -> standing for a version.

Comment: None of the value columns in the source table allow nulls, right? A replicated row with `1`, NULL, NULL, NULL, `5` would be only a bit perplexing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by combining your versioning and your value into a single binary column, then selecting the max. The query in it's shortest form would be:

```
SELECT  t.ID,
        Value1 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), SUBSTRING(MAX(CONVERT(BINARY(4), t.Versioning) 
                    + CONVERT(VARBINARY(50), t.Value1)), 5, 50)),
        Value2 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), SUBSTRING(MAX(CONVERT(BINARY(4), t.Versioning) 
                    + CONVERT(VARBINARY(50), t.Value2)), 5, 50)),
        Value3 = CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(MAX(CONVERT(BINARY(4), t.Versioning) 
                    + CONVERT(VARBINARY(50), t.Value3)), 5, 50))
FROM    YourTable AS t
GROUP BY ID;
```

To explain what is going on, I will focus on just value 3, with cutdown sample data.

The first step in the process is just to combine the ordering column, and the value column into a single binary value:

```
SELECT  *,
        BinaryValue3 = CONVERT(BINARY(2), t.Versioning)  + CONVERT(BINARY(2), t.Value3)     
FROM    (VALUES (1, 2, 1), (1, 4, 2), (1, NULL, 3)) AS t (ID, Value3, Versioning)
```

Which gives:

```
ID      Value3  Versioning      BinaryValue3
--------------------------------------
1       2           1           0x00010002
1       4           2           0x00020004
1       NULL        3           NULL
```

We then take the maximum of the binary value. This relies on two things:

1. The fact that concatenating NULL will yield NULL, so there is only a binary value for non-null records
2. Since binary values will sort from left to right, the `MAX` function will always pick up the binary value with the highest versioning number

Then once we have our maximum binary value (`0x00020004`), it is just  a case of extracting the right hand side, and converting it back to the original data type.

**Full Working Demo**

```
DECLARE @T TABLE 
(
    ID INT NOT NULL, 
    Value1  VARCHAR(50), 
    Value2 VARCHAR(50), 
    value3 INT, 
    Versioning INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID, Versioning)
);
INSERT @T (ID, Value1, Value2, Value3, Versioning)
VALUES
    (1, 'sport', 'tennis', 2, 1),
    (1, NULL, NULL, 4, 2),
    (1, NULL, 'football', NULL, 3),
    (1, 'game', NULL, NULL, 4);

SELECT  t.ID,
        Value1 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), SUBSTRING(MAX(CONVERT(BINARY(4), t.Versioning) 
                    + CONVERT(VARBINARY(50), t.Value1)), 5, 50)),
        Value2 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), SUBSTRING(MAX(CONVERT(BINARY(4), t.Versioning) 
                    + CONVERT(VARBINARY(50), t.Value2)), 5, 50)),
        Value3 = CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(MAX(CONVERT(BINARY(4), t.Versioning) 
                    + CONVERT(VARBINARY(50), t.Value3)), 5, 50))
FROM    @T AS t
GROUP BY ID;
```

You can also use this method with window functions to add the last non-null value to each row, so if you wanted to fill in all nulls, with the last non null value you can:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE 
(
    ID INT NOT NULL, 
    Value1  VARCHAR(50), 
    Value2 VARCHAR(50), 
    value3 INT, 
    Versioning INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID, Versioning)
);
INSERT @T (ID, Value1, Value2, Value3, Versioning)
VALUES
    (1, 'sport', 'tennis', 2, 1),
    (1, NULL, NULL, 4, 2),
    (1, NULL, 'football', NULL, 3),
    (1, 'game', NULL, NULL, 4);

SELECT  t.ID,
        ActualValue1 = t.Value1,
        ActualValue2 = t.Value2,
        ActualValue3 = t.Value3,
        LastNonNUllValue1 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), SUBSTRING(MAX(Value1Bin) OVER(PARTITION BY t.ID ORDER BY t.Versioning), 5, 50)),
        LastNonNUllValue2 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), SUBSTRING(MAX(Value2Bin) OVER(PARTITION BY t.ID ORDER BY t.Versioning), 5, 50)),
        LastNonNUllValue3 = CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(MAX(Value3Bin) OVER(PARTITION BY t.ID ORDER BY t.Versioning), 5, 50)),
        t.Versioning
FROM    @T AS t
        CROSS APPLY
        (   SELECT  Value1Bin = CONVERT(BINARY(4), t.Versioning) + CONVERT(VARBINARY(50), t.Value1),
                    Value2Bin = CONVERT(BINARY(4), t.Versioning) + CONVERT(VARBINARY(50), t.Value2),
                    Value3Bin = CONVERT(BINARY(4), t.Versioning) + CONVERT(VARBINARY(50), t.Value3)
        ) AS b
ORDER BY t.Versioning;
```

Which gives:

```
ID  ActualValue1    ActualValue2    ActualValue3    LastNonNUllValue1   LastNonNUllValue2   LastNonNUllValue3   Versioning
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   sport           tennis          2               sport               tennis                  2                   1
1   NULL            NULL            4               sport               tennis                  4                   2
1   NULL            football        NULL            sport               football                4                   3
1   game            NULL            NULL            game                football                4                   4
```

For more reading see [Itzik Ben-Gan's The Last non NULL Puzzle](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/last-non-null-puzzle)

Answer (score 1):

This is rather tricky in SQL Server, because it does not support the `ignore null`s option on window functions.  You can use repetitive `apply`s, one for each column:

```
select t.id, t1.value1, t2.value2, t3.value3
from (values (1)) t(id) outer apply
     (select top (1) t2.value1
      from yourtable t1
      where t1.id = t.id and t1.value1 is not null
      order by t1.versioning desc
     ) t1 outer apply 
     (select top (1) t2.value1
      from yourtable t2
      where t2.id = t.id and t2.value1 is not null
      order by t2.versioning desc
     ) t2 outer apply 
     (select top (1) t3.value1
      from yourtable t3
      where t3.id = t.id and t3.value1 is not null
      order by t3.versioning desc
     ) t3;
```

Answer (score 1):

With a `CTE` that returns the `[Versioning]` for the latest non null value of each of the columns `[ValueX]` and then joins to the table:

```
with cte as (
  select [ID],
    max(case when [Value1] is not null then [Versioning] end) v1,
    max(case when [Value2] is not null then [Versioning] end) v2,
    max(case when [Value3] is not null then [Versioning] end) v3
  from tablename
  group by [ID]
)
select c.[ID], t1.[Value1], t2.[Value2], t3.[Value3]
from cte c
inner join tablename t1 on t1.[ID] = c.[ID] and t1.[Versioning] = c.v1
inner join tablename t2 on t2.[ID] = c.[ID] and t2.[Versioning] = c.v2
inner join tablename t3 on t3.[ID] = c.[ID] and t3.[Versioning] = c.v3
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2b7916c754db445322458ecbeaf3ee7d).
Results:

```
> ID | Value1 | Value2   | Value3
> -: | :----- | :------- | :-----
>  1 | game   | football | 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet one more option.

Here we **unpivot** your data, and then **pivot**

**Example**

```
Select *
 From  (
        Select Top 1 with ties 
               A.ID
              ,B.*
         From  YourTable A
         Cross Apply ( values ('Value1',Value1)
                             ,('Value2',Value2)
                             ,('Value3',convert(varchar(50),Value3))
                     ) B(Item,Value)
          Where Value is not null
          Order By row_number() over (partition by id,item order by versioning desc)
       ) pvt
 Pivot (max(value) for item in ([Value1],[Value2],[Value3]) ) pvt
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Value1  Value2      Value3
1   game    football    4
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your table is 'tablename' and following code gives latest value and can be expandable to any other columns

```
select 
(SELECT TOP 1 Value1 FROM tablename WHERE Value1 IS NOT NULL ORDER BY Versioning desc) Value1,
(SELECT TOP 1 Value2 FROM tablename WHERE Value2 IS NOT NULL ORDER BY Versioning desc) Value2,
(SELECT TOP 1 Value3 FROM tablename WHERE Value3 IS NOT NULL ORDER BY Versioning desc) Value3
```